# Clear HTML inside surrounding table cell

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

How would I use jQuery to clear the HTML of a `<td>` element? I have a picture that, when clicked, triggers an Ajax call to the database. In the `success` function of the ajax call, I want to clear out the specific `<td>` element this pic is housed in and fill with the returned results. This pic resides in a grid that will contain a number of clickable pics, all with the same functionality so I want to make sure I'm just clearing out the `<td>` element that the call came from.

**EDIT**

Here is my  most recent attempt

```
        $('.checkErrors').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetErrors","AgentTransmission")',
                data: { term: $(this).attr('id') },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                    $("td", this).empty();
                }
            });
        });
```

This is the HTML (w/Razor Syntax as it's from an ASP MVC page) the call originates from

```
    <td align=center id=@item.ID>
        @if(item.RecordStatus.Equals("E"))
        {
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/magnify.gif")" class="checkErrors" id=@item.ID alt="Program Details" />
        }
    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event callback you have access to the element that was clicked. So it would look something like:

```
$("img").click(function() {
  //save the element that contains the image
  var td = $(this).parent();
  $.ajax({...
    success: function(data) {
      //use the saved element
      td.html('');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting though, it seems you cannot access `$(this).parent()` from inside the `success` call. Do you know why it's necessary to place the element in the `td` variable in order to alter/manipulate later?

Comment: `this` is a fun topic in JavaScript. Each time a function is executed, `this` is set to a specific value. jQuery intentionally sets it to the event target in the click event callback function. I'm not sure what it's set to in the success callback, but it will definitely be set to something else (or undefined). You might want to read this article: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Answer (score 0):

Is `$(this).closest("td").empty()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: lol nope that cleared the entire grid. I think that's close tho

Comment: Well, not exactly that. You should work the selector to match your current td.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var td = clickedImg.parentNode;
td.removeChild(clickedImg);
td.innerHTML = newText;
```